# PyTorch "modified by inplace operation" error

Tags: pytorch, autodiff

The error message indicates that `[torch.cuda.FloatTensor [256, 1, 4, 4]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead`, and execution breaks on `d_loss.backward()` — i.e., the backward call on my Discriminator.

UPDATE: Okay, I tracked it down to an `optimizer.step()` for my Generator that was happening before running `.backward()` on my Discriminator.

UPDATE 2: So once I got the model running on PyTorch 1.5 (by moving G's optimizer to after the `d_loss.backward()` call, as above), I noticed that losses were suddenly much higher during training. I let the model run for a few epochs and the images were basically noise. So, out of curiosity I switched back to my PyTorch 1.4 environment and ran the original for a few epochs, and the images were good again. It's a ClusterGAN that I'm training — so not the standard routine — and I'm wondering why this change is so detrimental to the output. Also, how can I get the model to run in PyTorch 1.5 without the degradation in performance? Presumably I have to keep the optimizer update where it was originally (right after `ge_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)`), but somehow avoid the error PyTorch 1.5 reports when we hit `d_loss.backward()` later in the code. I suppose I have to `clone()` something, but I'm not clear what... ?

```
[...]
# main training block
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for i, (imgs, itruth_label) in enumerate(dataloader):
            iter_count += 1
            # Ensure generator/encoder are trainable
            generator.train()
            encoder.train()
            # Zero gradients for models
            generator.zero_grad()
            encoder.zero_grad()
            discriminator.zero_grad()

            # Configure input
            real_imgs = Variable(imgs.type(Tensor))

            # ---------------------------
            #  Train Generator + Encoder
            # ---------------------------

            optimizer_GE.zero_grad()

            # Sample random latent variables
            zn, zc, zc_idx = sample_z(shape=imgs.shape[0],
                                      latent_dim=latent_dim,
                                      n_c=n_c)

            # Generate a batch of images
            gen_imgs = generator(zn, zc)

            # Discriminator output from real and generated samples
            D_gen = discriminator(gen_imgs)
            D_real = discriminator(real_imgs)

            # Step for Generator & Encoder, n_skip_iter times less than for discriminator
            did_update = False
            if (i % n_skip_iter == 0):
                # Encode the generated images
                enc_gen_zn, enc_gen_zc, enc_gen_zc_logits = encoder(gen_imgs)

                # Calculate losses for z_n, z_c
                zn_loss = mse_loss(enc_gen_zn, zn)
                zc_loss = xe_loss(enc_gen_zc_logits, zc_idx)

                # additional top-k step (from Sinha et al, 2020)
                if top_k <= D_gen.size()[0]:
                    top_k_gen = torch.topk(D_gen, top_k, 0)
                else:
                    top_k_gen = torch.topk(D_gen, D_gen.size()[0], 0) 

                # Check requested metric
                if wass_metric:
                    # Wasserstein GAN loss

                    ge_loss = torch.mean(top_k_gen[0]) + betan * zn_loss + betac * zc_loss
                else:
                    # Vanilla GAN loss
                    valid = Variable(Tensor(gen_imgs.size(0), 1).fill_(1.0), requires_grad=False)
                    v_loss = bce_loss(D_gen, valid)
                    ge_loss = v_loss + betan * zn_loss + betac * zc_loss

                ge_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
                # ---- ORIGINAL OPTIMIZER UPDATE ---- #
                optimizer_GE.step()
                scheduler.step(epoch + i / iters)
                did_update = True

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            optimizer_D.zero_grad()

            # Measure discriminator's ability to classify real from generated samples
            if wass_metric:
                # Gradient penalty term
                grad_penalty = calc_gradient_penalty(discriminator, real_imgs, gen_imgs)

                # Wasserstein GAN loss w/gradient penalty
                d_loss = torch.mean(D_real) - torch.mean(D_gen) + grad_penalty

            else:
                # Vanilla GAN loss
                fake = Variable(Tensor(gen_imgs.size(0), 1).fill_(0.0), requires_grad=False)
                real_loss = bce_loss(D_real, valid)
                fake_loss = bce_loss(D_gen, fake)
                d_loss = (real_loss + fake_loss) / 2

            d_loss.backward()
            # --- REVISED OPTIMIZER UPDATE FOR PyTorch 1.5 ------ #
            # if did_update:
            #     optimizer_GE.step()
            optimizer_D.step()
            # scheduler.step(epoch + i / iters)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the error occurs at the second time you call `.backward()`.
The problem is caused by calling `.backward()` on `D_gen` and `D_real` twice.
I don't know exactly what you're doing with this model, but I guess you don't have to backward and update the parameters of Discriminators while training Generators, right?

So, try this:

1.set the `requires_grad` of `D.parameters()` to `False` in the `Train Generator + Encoder` stage

2.set the `requires_grad` of `D.parameters()` to `True` in the `Train Discriminator` stage